# camel - sftp delete=true, would work with disconnect=true?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

In our sftp route, we have set `delete=true`, but file processing takes about 40 minutes to complete. now when route tries to delete file after completion, we get `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot delete file:` due to pipe closed `IOException`. I am assuming remote sftp server has closed the connection.

Now, if I add `disconnect=true`, would it disconnect as soon as file transfer is done? if so, would it reconnect for delete operation on route  completion or would I have to use some other config to keep connection live?

Because of this, one file is processed multiple times. (I could add `move` param for this, but we would still see delete operation failed exception)

**v2.12.2**

Comment: which version of camel are you using

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10712

Comment: Thanks, camel version I am using was `v2.12.2` - I will upgrade camel version.

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: yup... sure will do : )